# Order elements in Pentaho Report Designer in a Group Header

Tags: sql, sorting, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I know that PRD doesn't do any ordering, but rather takes in ordered data through SQL and displays them. This has worked for elements in the Details section but doesn't seem to work for group headers.

Example:
I have a report that displays a list of cars and are grouped by the header 'Product Line'. The groups are sorted in alphabetical order but I would like to have this order reversed. [This query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqv34.png) successfully sorts the data on the 'Buy Price' column, but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOBZO.png) does not sort on the 'Product Line' column like I expected.

Is there a way of reversing the order, so instead of 'Classic Cars' first, it's 'Vintage Cars'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to create another column in the database which was the reverse order of the one I wanted and then sort using that instead

Answer (score 2):

Could you try to set auto-sort=false in the master report?